# My for each loop is missing the first data set in my array

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I am sending this data set from a form. Each dataset is the exact same but only the event[1] & event[2] are inserting (I verified this using different data sets). This remains the same no matter how many arrays I add event[0] data never inserts into my database.

```
event[0][equipTypeUpdate]: 2
event[0][productTypeUpdate]: 33
event[0][serialNumUpdate]: 123456
event[0][assestNumUpdate]: 123456
event[0][payNumUpdate]: 1234596
event[0][warrantyEndDate]: 2020-10-05
event[0][statusUpdate]: No
event[0][installedInRoom]: No
event[0]siteNameUpdate]: 9
event[0][roomNameUpdate]: 1
event[1][equipTypeUpdate]: 2
event[1][productTypeUpdate]: 33
event[1][serialNumUpdate]: 123456
event[1][assestNumUpdate]: 123456
event[1][payNumUpdate]: 123156
event[1][warrantyEndDate]: 2020-10-05
event[1][statusUpdate]: No
event[1][installedInRoom]: No
event[1][siteNameUpdate]: 9
event[1][roomNameUpdate]: 1
event[2][equipTypeUpdate]: 2
event[2][productTypeUpdate]: 33
event[2][serialNumUpdate]: 123456
event[2][assestNumUpdate]: 123456
event[2][payNumUpdate]: 123156
event[2][warrantyEndDate]: 2020-10-05
event[2][statusUpdate]: No
event[2][installedInRoom]: No
event[2][siteNameUpdate]: 9
event[2][roomNameUpdate]: 1
```

This is my foreach loop that cycles through the arrays to save them as variables to insert into the database. I am thinking its a misplaced } here is the issue but can't seem to figure it out.
Any help appreciated thanks

```
if(is_post_request()) {
  if (isset($_POST["event"])) {
              $events = $_POST["event"];
  }
  foreach ($events as $event) {
    // code...
  $equipIdValue = $event['equipTypeUpdate'];
  $prodValue= $event['productTypeUpdate'];
  $serialValue= $event['serialNumUpdate'];
  $assetValue = $event['assestNumUpdate'];
  $paymentValue = $event['payNumUpdate'];
  $warrantyValue = $event["warrantyEndDate"];
  $installedValue = $event["installedInRoom"];
  $buildValue = $event["siteNameUpdate"];
  $statusValue = $event["statusUpdate"];
  $roomValue = $event["roomNameUpdate"];

  $timeStamWar = strtotime($warrantyValue);
  $siteValue = $_SESSION['location'];
  create_inventory($equipIdValue ,$prodValue ,$siteValue, $buildValue, $statusValue , $serialValue, $roomValue, $installedValue, $assetValue, $paymentValue, $timeStamWar);
}
 echo "New record created successfully";
 $lastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($db);
redirect_to("../Pages/my_site_stock.php?id=$timeStamWar");

}
else{
      // INSERT FAILED
      echo mysqli_error($db);
      db_disconnect($db);
      exit;
    }
```

```
function create_inventory($equipIdValue ,$prodValue ,$siteValue, $buildValue, $statusValue , $serialValue, $roomValue, $installedValue, $assetValue, $paymentValue, $timeStamWar){
// SQl statement to input form data in SQL table
    global $db;
    $sqllogin = "INSERT INTO av_inventory (equipment, product, site, current_location, status, serial, stored_room, installed, asset_tag, po_number, warranty) VALUES (? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqllogin)) {
        header("Location: ../Pages/update_inventory.php?error=sqlerror2");
         exit();
         }
        // otherwise go ahead
        else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssss", $equipIdValue , $prodValue, $siteValue, $buildValue, $statusValue , $serialValue, $roomValue, $installedValue, $assetValue, $paymentValue, $timeStamWar);
               mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);}
  }
```

EDIT:

From advice in the comments I did a vardump on $events and $event.
They do not seem to be getting the event[0] data which is odd become chrome developer tools under the network section shows my forms post data sending

```
event[0][equipTypeUpdate]: 1
event[0][productTypeUpdate]: 2
event[0][serialNumUpdate]: 123456
event[0][assestNumUpdate]: 123456
event[0][payNumUpdate]: 1234596
event[0][warrantyEndDate]: 2020-10-12
event[0][statusUpdate]: No
event[0][installedInRoom]: No
event[0]siteNameUpdate]: 9
event[0][roomNameUpdate]: 3
```

EDIT 2.0

```
A few of my variables were single quotes and some were doubles.
Issue is fixed thanks for the help
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do here, is just debug each step. Before your `foreach ($events as $event) {` dump out the value of `$events` and make sure they are all there.

If they are then dump out all the values that are going into the `create_inventory` function.

There isn't one correct answer to your question because there could be multiple places where the data isn't coming in, but its most likely that your post data doesn't contain the first array

Comment: Thanks very much that seems to be the issue. the $events variable is missing all the event[0] data which is odd as chrome developer tools shows that it is sending.

Comment: A few of my variables were single quotes and some were doubles.
Issue is fixed thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!